# How to center the text in the middle of donut hole pie chart?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, easypie

I want to create a donut hole pie chart to represent my data.
I came across this site : http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/ .
I follow their instruction all the way toward the end. I am close to get it working, but I don't know how to center the text in the middle of my pie chart.

Can someone help me with that ?

This is what I have so far.

```
    <div class="chart_1" data-percent="90" >
        <span>6</span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.chart_1').easyPieChart({

                             //Configuration goes here
                             easing: 'easeOutElastic',
                             delay: 3000,
                             barColor: '62ae41',
                             scaleColor: false,
                             lineWidth: 10,
                             trackWidth: 10,
                             animate: false,
                             lineCap: 'square',

                            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my result...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it centered just with a slight modification:

- added a "#" to the barColor
- removed a trailing comma

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('.chart_1').easyPieChart({
          //Configuration goes here
          easing: 'easeOutElastic',
          delay: 3000,
          barColor: '#62ae41',
          scaleColor: false,
          lineWidth: 10,
          trackWidth: 10,
          animate: false,
          lineCap: 'square'
      });
  });
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/imamathwiz/gu3aL84e/